# Почему в django CustomUserCreationForm два раза повторяется ввод пароля?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Пишу проект на django и столкнулся с проблемой в использовании `CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm)`.

Так выглядит мой **CustomUserCreationForm**:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    groups = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomGroup.objects.exclude(name="Жабо-проггеры"))

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "groups")
        labels = {
            'email': 'E-mail',
            'first_name': 'Имя',
            'last_name': 'Фамилия',
        }
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
        }

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if MyUser.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(email="").exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Такой E-mail уже существует!")
        return email
```

Так выглядит вызов формы на страницу:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block title %} Регистрация {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">"Регистрация"</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

И так выглядит **SignUpView**:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage')
    template_name = "signup.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            return redirect("homepage")
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Итак, проблема:

При регистрации пользователя сначала появляется следующая форма:

[image: Первая регистрация]

А потом появляется вот эта форма:
[image: Вторая регистрация]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы либо во второй форме не появлялись поля для ввода паролей, либо они в себе содержали пароль введенный ранее, либо чтобы сразу возникала вторая форма для регистрации?

Я пробовал переопределить поля для паролей:

```
password1 = None
password2 = None
```

Однако это лишь убирало их во второй форме, но после попытки регистрации вызывался Exception, говорящий, что не хватает password1 и password2